# floating point numbers in C slightly different from expected

Tags: c, floating-point, precision

I noticed that in C, a float can be as small as 2^-149, and as large as 2^127. If I try to set the float to any smaller or larger respectively than these, then I get zero and inf, respectively. The 2^149 doesn't make sense to me; where does it come from?

It appears that the exponent is 8 bits, so we can have 2^-128 to 2^127. The overall sign of the float is 1 bit, so that leaves 23 bits for the significand since a float is 32 bits total. If all 23 bits of the significand are placed after the binary "decimal point" such that the significand is <= 0.5, then we should be able to have floats as small as 2^(-128-23) = 2^-151. On the other hand, if one of the 23 bits is placed BEFORE the binary "decimal" point such that the significand is <= 1, then we would have the smallest float be 2^(-128-22) = 2^-150. Both of these do not agree with the fact that the smallest float seems to be 2^-149. Why is this?

Comment: IIRC, the highest and lowest exponents are reserved for infinities, NaNs, denormals and zero.

Comment: Immibis is correct. There's a good explanation here: http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/float.html

Answer (score 0):

Infinity (+ or -) is represented by the maximum exponent (all 1 bits), and zero mantissa. NaN is represented by the maximum exponent, and any non-zero mantissa.

Denormal numbers, and zero, are represented with the minimum exponent (all 0 bits).

So those two exponents are not available for normal numbers.